# VS 2013 saved file when not asked to

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was just doing a find & replace in my project and unintentionally replaced some things in the Windows MFC header `afxwin.h`.

Visual Studio showed a star on the tab name, i.e. `afxwin.h*`, indicating that it had in fact been modified (side question: why are these headers not read-only?). I closed out of Visual Studio **with `afxwin.h*` showing** and it did not ask me if I wanted to save the changes or not. I went to the disk location for the header file and saw the changes had been committed without prompt.

Is this really the intended functionality? I get notifications whenever I close out of Visual Studio if there are uncommitted changes; why not for this? Now I'm a little worried that it's going to save things on exit without my choice in the matter.